# htaccess file making signin redirect to home page and start a new session

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, session, redirect

My host company created a redirect in my htaccess file so that all of my pages are using my SSL cert and display as https. Since they did this I am unable to login to my site on the first attempt. It redirects me to my index.php page and starts a new session. Before doing this redirect, my session would carry forward when signing on. Which I need as I am designing an ecommerce website and want the items in the cart to move forward if they sign in.

htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Sign in page that redirects to my Signed-in index page. As you can see there is not a redirect on this to index.php...only the signed in index or an error would display. Something is causing the htaccess file to redirect me to my index page and start the new session. The thing is after I have attempted to sign in for the first time, the google chrome remember password feature displays, but I'm not logged in. When I try to login after I'm redirected, it allows me.

```
if(Input::exists()) {
if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array('required' => true),
        'password' => array('required' => true)
    ));

    if($validation->passed()) {
        $user = new User();

        $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
        $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);

        if($login) {
            Redirect::to('indexSignedIn.php');
        } else {
            $tryagain = "The information you entered did not match our records.";
        }

    } else {
        foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br>';
        }
    }
```

What could be causing this redirect and is there anyway to fix it so I can login on my first attempt and not loose my session?-

Edit::: Sign In Form added

```
<?php
if(Session::exists('home')) {
    echo '<p>' . Session::flash('home') . '</p>';
}
 ?> 
                <form class="signinform" name="Sign In" action="" method="post" autocomplete="on" accept-charset= "utf-8">
                    <span class="spancenter"><h1>Sign In</h1></span>
                    <hr><br>
                    <div class="centerleft">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" class="biginputbar" autocomplete="on" required>

                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="biginputbarp" autocomplete="off" required>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="field"> 
                        <label for="remember">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"> Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div><br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
                        <label for="widebutton"> 
                                <input id="widebutton" type="submit" value="Sign In"> 
                        </label><br><br>
```

Config

```
<?php
class Config {
public static function get ($path = null) {
    if($path) {
        $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
        $path = explode('/', $path);

        foreach($path as $bit) {
            if(isset($config[$bit])){
                $config = $config[$bit];
            }
        }
        return $config;
    }
    return false;
}
}
?>
```

Cookie class:

```
<?php
class Cookie {
public static function exists($name) {
    return (isset($_COOKIE[$name])) ? true : false;
}

public static function get($name) {
    return $_COOKIE[$name];
}

// view video 19 a little after 4 minutes to see this
public static function put($name, $value, $expiry) {
    if(setcookie($name, $value, time() + $expiry, '/')) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static function delete($name) {
    self::put($name, '', time() - 1);
}
 }
?>
```

Token

```
public static function check($token) {
    $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');

    if(Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)) {
        Session::delete($tokenName);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: As I understand, sessions won't carry over between http and https, so the only way will be to have them log in under https. Are there still parts of your site where the person can visit using a non-secure, http, url?

Comment: Every page on my site displays as https. The weird thing about all of this is say if you added products to the cart. Then tried to login, it creates the new session and takes you back to the index.php page. Then when you try logging in again it sends you through. But say I log out and close the website. Then if I enter my websites address in again and re-visit the page, my first session is still present.

Comment: my website is buyfarbest.com if you want to see exactly what it is doing.

Comment: Could you post your form html sourcecode on initial creation

Comment: I have added the form source code to my question

Comment: @dgig - of course they will, otherwise you'd never be able to take a shopping cart from a shop to checkout - have to get your cookie settings right though (assuming you're using cookie based sessions of course).

Comment: I'm not sure it is as simple as "of course they will". This is a common problem across different platforms. http://solotandem.com/using-mixed-https-sessions-securely-and-without-loss-session-data https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/340

Comment: I added in my cookie and config class to see if that would help

Comment: Also as you can see in my sign in form I'm generating a token. I added my token class to my question. But you can see in it there is a SESSION delete for tokens. Could this be causing it?